# How to verify requests to my Parse.com app?

Tags: parse-platform, in-app-purchase

I have an app that uses parse.com as backend. 
If I want to store information about user's in-app purchases in table there, how can I be sure that some guy is not going to create a simple app where users of my app can log (like in my own) in and write in parse-tables whatever they want (for ex.: that they made in-apps when they really didn't). This info is used to give the user access to app's features so it's important that the user really paid for that.

Comment: I am building an web service for that, it's called mbaasy.com, i've actually created documentation on how to use parse.com with my service: https://mbaasy.com/docs/webhooks/#example-2-updating-a-parse-com-user-with-a-purchase. It's not live yet, but if you would like to be a beta tester please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the table name public knowledge, so don't ever access it directly from the app, always use cloud code. Pass the cloud code some salted hashed details to verify against, and do the verification on save of any new objects being added toot that table with a before save hook. Drop any new objects which don't pass the test.

Comment: What this "salted hashed details" could be like?

Comment: Salt would be an arbitrary string, obfuscated in the app, and combined with a date stamp and then hashed, for example. The date would be sent to the server, the salt is not and is hidden as best you can in the app code.

Comment: But how can I be sure that no one could sent same string with request?

Comment: The hash needs to verify the details sent, preferably all of them if you can, and you can also check the timestamps is within the last 30 seconds

Comment: But what is the difference - if my app sends it or someone's else app using same App Id and Client Id ???

Comment: it needs to be time sensitive, so the person would need to do it with a valid version of the app, steal it and then do it again from another app quickly - which is pointless for the attacker. if you need to prevent that then you need a tracking id which you can verify is unique too.